# Redmine: notify when commented issue is updated

Tags: redmine, redmine-plugins

Is there any plugin/patch/anything for notifying me by email, when issue which I commented in, is updated? Now I only receive notifications on my own issues, or ones that assigned to me. I know about "Watch" action, but is there a way to do it automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: https://github.com/mezza/redmine_auto_watch

Simple plugin to make autowatch on issue update.